# How to increase the buffer or 'count' size in MPI_BCAST?

Tags: mpi, fortran90

Given the following code, this runs successfully if isize<16000 and hangs otherwise.
How can I increase the size of the buffer/count to allow isize to be larger? (much larger. like 3M)

```
isize=size(x)
call MPI_BCAST(x,isize,MPI_REAL,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
```

Comment: What MPI implementation are you using?  Have you used a debugger to confirm that the code is "hung", or is it just "taking a really, really long time?"  How many ranks?  What is the interconnect between the ranks?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with the internal buffer size. 16k reals should pose no problem whatsoever for the MPI implementation (unless you are using a very obscure implementation... if you go with OpenMPI or MPICH2 you should be fine).

Just to be sure, I just successfully broadcasted 16M values and without problem.

So my guess is that either you're using too many ranks (and killing off your network that is not able to handle the load), or you have another problem with your hardware setup.